# Appdelegate is not called in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, appdelegate

I create an OS X app in XCode. but it doesn't work. When i launch this app in XCode, my window does not appear. and there is any log. I think the problem is 'Appdelegate is not called'. I already check my referencing outlets, but there is nothing special. I also check my storyboard entry point(initial controller).

Here is my Appdelegate.

Appdelegate:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwoEG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDxAg.png)

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"applicationWillFinishLaunching");}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to initialize your application
NSLog(@"applicationDidFinishLaunching");}
```

I'm not good at English. sorry.
What can I do?

Comment: in the StoryBoard check your Application scene->Application->App Delegate

Comment: Application Scene
  {Application
  ,App Delegate
  ,First Responder
  ,Font Manager}
Application and App Delegate are same location. down the Application scene. I create a new project and compare it with my project. but there is no problem. :(

Comment: I found the problem in my code. :D. thank you.